# How to connect to external database in wordpress?

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I have two website one uses WordPress as landing page `https://covid19.com/`  and the second one is react app `https://app.covid19.com/` now I would like to pull data from react app to WordPress (landing page), After checking docs and google articles, as they suggest to use `wpdb` to connect to an external database

Here is what I have so far

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'school');

$mydb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);

$rows = $mydb->get_results("select * from users");

var_dump($rows);

exit;

?>
```

Note: here is my php functions [my functions.php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53a0594f0167578f767294d79548fe94fae800c5)

Now, where do I put this connection in functions.php if yes how?

Comment: you need to use the IP address for the other apache server, and you need to allow Remote host for your current IP server from the other server

Comment: @BurhanKashour do you have docs on that? Does it look like you complicating here?

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/connect-access-remote-mysql-database-cpanel-php/

Comment: @BurhanKashour that is not wordpress I need to connect using wordpress using wpdb

Comment: Well, then see this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database

Answer (score 1):

You're defining variables as constants, which you don't need... But also you call them as variables instead of constants.

So either do this.

```
$DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = 'password';
$DB_NAME = 'school';
```

OR

```
$mydb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

Although I think the latter isn't a great choice.

You could then do

```
global $mydb;
$mydb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);
```

So that anywhere else in your code, you can call your $mydb by calling global $mydb